# How does `Import Native` work in Elm

Tags: d3.js, elm

In an older library attempting to join [Elm and D3](https://github.com/seliopou/elm-d3) I noticed certain statements importing Native JavaScript...

```
import Native.D3.Render
import Native.D3.Selection
import Native.D3.Transition
```

Can we just compile native JavaScript with `elm-make` ...? I know we are discouraged from writing our own JavaScript (since it is not type-safe) but sometimes it's necessary.

The [elm-package.json](https://github.com/seliopou/elm-d3/blob/master/elm-package.json) shows this was written in `0.15` or `0.16` so it does not compile under the new syntax change.

---

Here is an `elm-package.json`

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "summary": "helpful summary of your project, less than 80 characters",
    "repository": "https://github.com/user/project.git",
    "license": "BSD3",
    "source-directories": [
        "."
    ],
    "native-modules": true,
    "exposed-modules": [],
    "dependencies": {
        "elm-lang/core": "4.0.1 <= v < 5.0.0",
        "elm-lang/html": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0",
        "elm-lang/svg": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0",
        "evancz/elm-graphics": "1.0.0 <= v < 2.0.0"
    },
    "elm-version": "0.17.0 <= v < 0.18.0"
}
```

with a fuction that imports a native library

```
import Native.Test
import Html exposing (text)

main = text "Hello, World!"
```

it compiled

```
john@miCasa:~/Documents/Elm$ elm-make test-native.elm
Success! Compiled 1 module.                                         
Successfully generated index.html
```

---

Motivation for looking into Native code comes from looking at a library called [Elm-D3](https://github.com/seliopou/elm-d3) which uses native types.  Essentially, he creates a type `D3` which maps to the [d3js](https://github.com/d3/d3) library.  A few problems:

- This library binds Elm 0.16 to D3 3.0
- Elm is now at 0.17 and D3JS is at 4.0

However, there seems to be an active [issue](https://github.com/seliopou/elm-d3/issues/34) on this very topic at the moment.

Comment: Yes, you still can use native modules, the API for writing modules in JavaScript is not documented yet. Can you please be more specific with your question?

Comment: @halfzebra this is reallly great news... I'll get back to you :D

Answer (score 0):

Part of the Native modules is implemented in JS.

When you build an app that uses Native libraries, that JS code gets transferred into the bundle that `elm-make` creates.

Here is [a link to an article about writing a Native function](https://github.com/NoRedInk/take-home/wiki/Writing-your-first-Elm-Native-module).

Comment: All of the native modules are implemented in JS at the moment. This is an outdated tutorial for `0.16.0`, which is not relevant anymore.